# When do the colors in the custom color palette of terminator kick-in?

Tags: linux, terminal, terminator

In terminator it is possible to choose your own color palette, see [image: screenshot]

I was wondering when these colors actually are used. I know that some of them are used for decoration, other are dependend on the file permission or type. But I can't find a documentation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When do the colors in the custom color palette of terminator kick-in?

They are used for when [ANSI color escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) are replaced by actual colors. The colors in order correspond to numbers of ANSI escape codes in 2*8 color palette, most probably the upper row is for normal colors and the bottom row are bright colors.

So they "kick in" when a program outputs an ansi escape code for this color.

Comment: This would mean that the program `ls` actually prints these escape codes along the output? Is this right?

Also, what about coloring the prompt? Does, in my case, `zsh` pass color codes to `terminator`?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes.  3. Print color codes from your prompt. There are endless tutorials on the net about how to customize prompt line. 4. I have no idea what _your_ zsh does.

Comment: 3 and 4 were relating to the same thing. 4 isn't about what my, your or any zsh is doing. The question is rather, is this, the color escape codes, decided by the shell one is using?

Comment: `is this decided by the shell one is using?` Sorry, what is decided? Yes, shell "controls" it's prompt line.

Comment: The coloring of the prompt. I editted the question.